# Where do I install the bootloader for a dual-boot system?

Tags: installation, windows-7, bootloader

This may be an odd question, but whenever I start up 12.04 installation from my flashdrive, it finishes installation. Then, at the end of the installation it says "Failed to install bootloader, would you like to install it elsewhere?" and it gives me an option of where to install it. Where do I install it to to make sure my windows 7 isn't rendered useless like last time? Included info: I [will] have a few partitions.
1) The 100Gb "System" thingie
2) Windows 7
3) Ubuntu 12.04

Which do I install the bootloader to? (in terms of /dev/sda/, because I dunno how to tell the difference between the names) xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are dual-booting, the boot-loader should go on **`/dev/sda`** itself. Yes, NOT `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sda2`, or any other partition, but on the *hard drive itself.*

Then, at each boot, Grub will ask you to choose between Ubuntu or Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, nowadays this depends on whether your booting system is of traditional (legacy, BIOS, as in this post of 4 years ago) or UEFI type (in circulation since 2012). Please consider this other answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/860311/446253