# I can't make my Windows 8 boot loader to run Ubuntu or even ask me which OS to run as dual boot!

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, configuration, windows-8

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 as secondary OS on my laptop. The primary OS I have is Windows 8.

So I have partitioned drive where NTFS is for Windows 8 and other partition is EXT4 for Ubuntu.

When I installed Ubuntu I picked the EXT4 partition and picked 3 boot loader options so far:

```
/dev/sta ATA HITACHI (750 GB) <-= this...
/dev/sta1 Windows 8 (loader) <-= and this...
/dev/sta2
/dev/sta5
/dev/sta6 Ubuntu 12.04 (12.04) <-= and this...
/dev/stb
```

After like 3 installations I still can't boot Ubuntu, nor can even see any boot loader... It goes straight to Windows 8 booting...

Please help! This has been very frustrating day and a half... And I don't think it should take that long to figure out =[

**ANSWER: I could not find a proper solution for my problem. I'm not sure if I encountered some drive corruption, or program glitch, the only solution that fixed my problem was to make drive back-up and completely re-partition my hard-drive. Please post if anyone encounter similar problem. As I really would like to know why my drive failed to install Ubuntu on my drive.**

Comment: The first one on the list should work.. Was there no effect at all?

Comment: No effect what so ever.

Comment: was your problem solved ?

Comment: Yes and no, I had to repartition my hard drive. I couldn't didn't find any other cause of this but partition table.

Comment: Please boot with Ubuntu Live CD and post the output of `sudo parted /dev/sda print` (or sta?). At least Windows 7 Boot Manager will boot only primary partitions [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829683(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_Step1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you use `/dev/sta6` for the grub bootloader. Next steps:

- Run `update-grub` to write the ubuntu bootsector
- Copy the ubuntu bootsector into a file: `dd if=/dev/sta6 of=boot.lnx bs=512 count=1`
- Transfer the file to the windows loader partition `/dev/sta1`, either by copying or via USB stick and booting to windows.

Then use these commands in windows shell to add a Linux selection to the windows loader:

```
bcdedit /create /d “Linux” /application BOOTSECTOR
```

BCDEdit will return an alphanumeric identifier for this entry that I will refer to as `{ID}` in the remaining steps. You’ll need to replace `{ID}` by the actual returned identifier. An example of `{ID}` is `{d7294d4e-9837-11de-99ac-f3f3a79e3e93}`. Next, let’s specify which partition hosts a copy of the boot.lnx file:

```
bcdedit /set {ID} device partition=c:
bcdedit /set {ID}  path \boot.lnx
bcdedit /displayorder {ID} /addlast
bcdedit /timeout 30
```

http://www.iceflatline.com/2009/09/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-linux-using-bcdedit/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Windows 8 is not 64-bit with the UEFI boot type, if it is pre-installed then it mean yes. If you run `dxdiag` and it says *Windows 8 64-bit* then it mean yes. If one or both are true then the basic thing you need is an ISO of Ubuntu 64-bit for installation, the rest goes here:

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: No, I had Windows 7 reinstalled, then formatted drive and installed Windows 8, Both 64-bit, and also Ubuntu was 64-bit. The link you provided was not helping as I didn't have any problems while booting, but to install the OS.

Comment: It means your Windows boot with ordinary EFI with MBR disk ?

Comment: MBR, I assume..

Comment: You formatted the whole drive ? it means you cleared all partition then installed Windows 8 64-bit ? if yes,it means Windows 8 automatically turn your disk to GPT

Comment: I originally had 7, then installed 8, then formatted to get Ubuntu on it. I don't know the details of what partitioning table they all use :P I i believe you're statement is mostly correct.