# Installing Ubuntu 14.10 and window Installation type

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, bootloader

I am installing Ubuntu and am stuck at one window that is called "Installation type"

I have 3 partitions on my hard disk: 80 GB NTFS, 140 GB NTFS and 15 GB EXT4 and want to install Ubuntu on the 3rd one - 15 GB EXT4.

When I get to the mentioned window I don't know what to choose...
What is meant by a device for bootloader installation?

This is how it looks like but this is NOT a screenshot of my laptop screen, I only found a similar picture on the internet.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to install bootloader when installing Ubuntu as secondary OS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219514/where-to-install-bootloader-when-installing-ubuntu-as-secondary-os)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the partition where you want to install it and press the "change" button. In that window, you should choose type ("ext4"), mount point ("/") and check the format box.

Linux call each HD as sdX, being  "a" the first one, so if you fisically have 3 HD, you will got in that list "sda, sdb and sdc".

If any of that fisical HD has a partition, Linux will call it as sdX1, sdX2...

So if you install Linux in a partition called sda2, on the "Device for boot..." section you should select "/dev/sda" in order to boot the system from that HD.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As you want to dual-boot Win and Ubuntu, I recommend you to replace Win's bootloader with Ubuntu's GRUB, because GRUB recognizes Windows and automatically adds it to its OS list and Windows does not - you would have to manually type it into boot.ini and please don't ask me how to do that.

So to use GRUB as standard boot loader, install it directly on the hard disk (sda) instead of a partition (Ubuntu: sda3, I think). If you installed it on Ubuntu's partition (sda3), you would have to find a way to chainload the GRUB bootloader via your standard bootloader (from Windows), which is pretty difficult but you would keep your old one as it is.
Using any other partitions (win system or data partitions) is totally senseless.

I hope I could help you if you didn't find a solution already. Please accept an answer to show your problem is solved and to improve your and the answerer's reputation!