# Ubuntu 16.04 does not start after installation next to Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Installation ends succesfully, computer restarts and... Windows boots up. 
   My computer: old laptop HP Compaq 6710b (no UEFI, no secure boot). 
Two hard drives: 
 - 1st is 240 GB SSD and 2nd is some old 200 GB HDD.
 
 - 2nd drive is installed in special adapter which fits in optical drive bay.

SSD is partitioned like this:
[image]

HDD has one partition:
[image]

Comment: Does the GRUB menu (OS selection) show or the Windows just boots immediately?

Comment: No menu pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that, during installation, it / you picked the wrong option in "device for bootloader installation". (See [here for a screenshot](https://askubuntu.com/a/219528/383125))

Your laptop presents the hard drive as `/dev/sda`, and the internal SSD as `/dev/sdb` (From the screenshot). Thus, the installer installed the bootloader onto `/dev/sda` by default (Assuming you didn't tell it to do otherwise).

The problem is that the laptop isn't looking on the HDD for the bootloader - it's looking on the SSD, and thus only sees the Windows 7 bootloader (Which is on the SSD, and not the Ubuntu one (grub), which is on the HDD.

---

See [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) for details on how to fix this, making sure you intall to `/dev/sdb`, or you can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for this.

Another, possibly easier, option is to set the boot order in the BIOS set-up, so that it is set to boot from the hard drive.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Also he could set the HDD before the SSD in the boot order.

Comment: Indeed, that's also an option, if the laptop supports booting from the HDD in the optical drive bay.

Comment: Boot-Repair did the trick. I quess it places grub on SDD drive.

Comment: Boot sequence setting - on the other hand - was usueles for me, cause there was no option to choose between HDD and SDD. When I invoke boot menu (using F9 on my computer), a see "USB Hard Drive" (when pendrive is connected), "laptop hard drive" (something like this) and "Ethernet" (or LAN something). It doesn't seem to notice that there are two drives installed.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to regain access to my Ubuntu with following set of commands:
sudo mount /dev/sdb8 /mnt 
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev/ && 
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc && 
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys 
sudo chroot /mnt 
grub-install /dev/sdb 
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb 
update-grub 
exit && 
sudo umount /mnt/sys && 
sudo umount /mnt/proc && 
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts && 
(All commands executed using Ubuntu 16.04 launched from USB drive.)