# Unable to boot 18.04 on HDD after fresh install

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, acer

Laptop was previously a Win10 system, Intel Core i5, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD.

Created a bootable USB key to install Ubuntu 18.04 (no dual boot) and after going through the whole process my expectation was that a simple reboot of the hardware would boot into Ubuntu.  I have done this before with different hardware using Ubuntu 16.04.

Result of reboot was a message from the system telling that no boot device could be found.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you say yes when asked to install Grub?

Comment: Acer has  an unique requirement of setting "trust" from within UEFI. Similar details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you disable secure boot?
F2/F12/Del on startup

Answer (score 0):

When following the install process, did you ensure to install grub to the MBR of your boot device (or rather the correct boot device)?

Usually it will be something like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/nvme0n1`.

There's a screenshot [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/219528/623338) that should help to show what I mean (although for an older Ubuntu installer).