# Ubuntu on a separate SSD

Tags: dual-boot

I have a NVME SSD with Windows 10 on it.

Today I bought a separate SSD for Ubuntu.

Tried installing Ubuntu, on the installation menu I chose `Something else`. Then I partitioned the second SSD, selected it for installation. Selected the second SSD for boot loader.

The problem is that my Ubuntu bootloader is installed on the older NVME SSD (Windows 10 drive).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you installing the bootloader on /dev/sda or /dev/sda1? This answer may help: https://askubuntu.com/a/219528/883129 Also What happened to your windows bootloader? Are your partitions GPT or MBR?

Comment: I'm installing it on /dev/sda, while the win ssd is /dev/nvme. Nothing happened to the Windows Boot Loader. I don't know whether they are GPT or MBR

Comment: If nothing happened to Windows, its bootloader must be used on win SSD. In that case how do you know if Ubuntu bootloader (grub) is also installed there? I am confused.

Comment: Because if I go to my BIOS and check boot options it says "ubuntu (NVME SSD)"
Also. If I assign a letter to the windows boot partition, ubuntu loader also sits here.

Comment: Can you try unconnecting win SSD, then intalling ubuntu again on the new drive. I also suggest to review GPT vs MBR, especially for dual boot systems.

Comment: You need gpt partitioning & an ESP - efi system partition. If drive is MBR, convert or totally erase it using gparted. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is how it installs.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI