# ubuntu failed to boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I have ubuntu installed on a USB flash drive and a grub bootloader that has automatically installed on my hard drive.

I installed grub on the `/boot/efi` partition on a pendrive (with `grub-install /dev/sda3` command), but when I want to boot ubuntu by selecting the boot option `ubuntu (USB)` instead of `ubuntu (SKHYNIX -...)` which is my hard drive I get `ubuntu failed to boot.` error.

How can I run Ubuntu from USB? (So that I can run them on any computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall your Ubuntu on USB.
In the installing procedures, there is a part to select which device to install bootloader.

Something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/219528/730458).

This time make sure you install `/boot/efi` partition on your pendrive but not your hard drive.

Comment: Should i choose /dev/sda (entire device) or /dev/sda3 (EFI type partition)?

Comment: In both options it still installed on hard drive, even though I chose a different drive.

Comment: Try to unplug your hard drive when installing ubuntu on your pendrive.

Comment: It worked, thanks!