# Where to install bootloader when installing a second Linux OS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, bootloader

I want to try Bodhi Linux (which is very close to Ubuntu) beside the already installed Lubuntu Quantual (which was in a dual boot with WinXP). So, I want a 3-boot: to chose between these three at boot.

I have shrinked Windows partition, created a 7 GB new one and want to put Bodhi there.

But didn't took the time to get all the info. Where to put the bootloader?

I have set it to the same partition where I set Bodhi to be installed. It is called `/dev/sda4` and is on the same partition table with all the others. But during install it says that setting bootloader there is impossible and I have several  options: change location of bootloader, continue without a bootloader and abort installation.

What to do?

Continuing without bootloader would keep the old Lubuntu bootloader and I'll have the 3-boot desired option in grub or what?

Should I follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/163721/47206) and others that recommend to put bootloader in `/dev/sda` or is that just for dual boot?

Comment: Have you tried installing without bootloader and then in your main OS running `update-grub`? The `os-prober` call should be able to find other OSs. Lots of heuristics there.

Comment: @gertvdijk - havent tried yet, im waiting for an answer with bodhi installation underway and midori open here :), afraid to break the eggs here, but it makes sense to me: i have a bootloader from lubuntu. but going without it here would just add bodhi to that list if i upgrade as you say?

Comment: "Should I follow this answer [...]" No. That's about Windows dual-boot with installing Ubuntu after a Windows single-boot.

Comment: @gertvdijk. ok, i'll try this then, as  don't see other way

Comment: `sudo update-grub` but [also](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275): "Lubuntu apparently doesn't ship with the package os-prober" <-- so install `os-prober` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience you should install the bootloader in the hard drive itself instead of a partition, most likely /dev/sda (unless you are using a mac with OSX where you need to install EFI in the hard drive and create a partition for the bootloader).

Every time you add a new distro grub checks for installed OSs in each partition and it will update your grub screen with an option for each OS.

The only thing that will happen is that some distros have a different look and feel for grub so it might not be as nice depending on what partition you install last.

Finally if you want to update your grub (because you broke it or don't like the looks of it) you can put a live cd (or usb or whatever you fancy) and fix it. There are some guides for it. My point there is that you can play around without actually losing information though backups are always in place ;)